# AppleScript: How to do shell script with admin privileges that only asks for password on first run/never?

Tags: terminal, applescript, script, administrator, root

I'm trying to write an AppleScript that will update the schedule boot/wake time of computer to be a hour from the time the script is run. My script below works, but every time I run it, I'm asked for admin password. Since I plan to schedule this to run hourly, how do I get this to run silently in the background?

Reason: Working remotely, I need remote Macs that get accidentally turned off, to automatically start no later than one hour after it's been turned off.

```
on run
    
    tell (current date) to set curHour to (its hours as string)
    tell (current date) to set curMin to (its minutes as string)
    
    if curHour + 1 > 23 then
        set newHour to "00"
    else
        set newHour to curHour + 1
    end if
    
    set newTime to newHour & ":" & curMin & ":" & "00" as string
    do shell script "pmset repeat wakeorpoweron MTWRFSU " & newTime with administrator privileges
    
end run
```

Comment: could you just call `sudo pmset repeat wakeorpoweron MTWRFSU` and then give your account permissions to run that command through `sudo` without a password?

Comment: That might work. Seems that on my first test, it asked for my password the first time, but then not follow up runs while still booted. Will test some more, but that might be it. Running it the first time isn't a deal-breaker if that's what Apple needs. Thanks!

Comment: Ah no, once I closed Script Editor and relaunched, it asked me for my password again. I don't have the part figured out yet where this will run hourly, but I may schedule it with Automator to see what happens.

Comment: But did you configure a `NOPASSWD` entry for the command in the sudoers configuration file?

Comment: I did not. I'm still relatively new to scripting, so I'm not sure what that is, but will be Googling profusely now.

Comment: @thrig I actually found a way to store the password in the AppleScript as a property, thereby only needing to enter it once. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/sudo-under-applescript.71060/post-874826